# Shooting towards mouse behaves wierdly - Java

Tags: java, math

In my game I use this code to shoot towards certain location (mouseX/Y). If the 
mouseX/Y is **same** the bullet goes in **right** direction, but when mouseX/Y is **different** (for example 20 and 10) then the bullet goes in totally **wrong** direction. Thanks for help!

```
double bulletVelocity = 3.0; //however fast you want your bullet to travel
//mouseX/Y = current x/y location of the mouse
//originX/Y = x/y location of where the bullet is being shot from

double angle = Math.atan2(mouseX - originX, mouseY - originY);
o.setVelX((float)((bulletVelocity) * Math.cos(angle)));
o.setVelY((float)((bulletVelocity) * Math.sin(angle)));
```

Comment: The docs for [atan2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)) say the inputs should be (y,x), is that the issue you're having?

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you.

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää Either of you, please make an answer or delete the question, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs for [atan2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)) say that you need to input the arguments in order `(y,x)`. This is a weird departure from the typical order probably fueled by the order in which you'd input those to division.